# Something that allows data access via API or feed?

Tags: database, web-services

I have a rather large user database with a lot of important information for the company I work for.

This database and all of the websites it feeds is behind a corporate firewall.  A lot of vendors that we are doing business with for a variety of tools would like to access my employee data.  However my data is not on the internet and there is no way they can reach the website.

Right now my server sends off automated reports nightly.  It does this by just emailing a csv file to the vendors.  I would like some kind of application to handle this data on the internet.  It would be better if it didn't require hosting but I can get hosting if it does that.

In a perfect world it would either take my database syncing (doubt this would work with proxy servers in the way) or just timely exports, and allow my vendors to login and view the data via a feed or API.  That way I can better manage the data and all of my vendors have the same thing.

More facts:  I am currently using MySQL, however I do not care what type of database takes the data.  I have experience in multiple database platforms, so I am dB agnostic.  The main feature I need from this software is to present the databased data in a way that vendors can easily pull it, yet secure because it is employee data.

As for OS, I use Windows but have access to linux/apache.  I would rather this be a cloud type service but if I need to get linux or windows based hosting I can do whatever.  Currently on our internal web servers everything is PHP/MySQL IIS7 Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: @Izzy - good points, will update question.

Comment: Raw idea: there's some kind of replication possible with MySQL (so a second copy of your database, or maybe even only the essential parts you wish, could be duplicated to the server). If there's no restriction to who of your customer shall be able to see what data, an encrypted connection (https) plus password-protected access to phpMyAdmin might fit your needs (customers could view and even export data that way).

Comment: @Izzy - Your assumption is that the people that work for our vendors are as smart as you.  Your idea is certainly feasible but I think some of our vendors would have issues using it - no joke.

Comment: That's why I made it a comment, not an answer – I know exactly what you're pointing at (don't ask me why, you know the answer :) But you definitely could use the first part (duplication). And as for phpMyAdmin: if you just need a button to "export", you either could code that yourself – or use a link to a prepared action.

Comment: and, if you plan to script it yourself, there is nothing better than https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/  It could fire up a browser, navigate to PhpMyAdmin, enter export details, push the "export" button, start your email and send the email.